# Best way to pass long arguments in a GoLang CLI program and its limitations

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I am writing a CLI program in GO and need to be able to pass a rather long list of arguments to the main function. At the moment I am using the standard way of passing arguments (space separated values) and then 
retrieve 'em using os.Args[index].

So my questions are:

1. Is there a limit to the number of arguments one can pass?
2. Is there a limit to the length of a string argument?
3. Is there any other way of achieving this and if so how?

Comment: The limits are all operating system dependent. You can pass args any other way you want, via files, serialized on stdin, environment variables, etc.

Comment: Have you considered using a package to help manage your command line arguments? A package like [urfave/cli](https://github.com/urfave/cli) might be useful.

Comment: Regarding Item 3 in your question, another way to achieve this -- I would suggest using a configuration file (something simple as yaml) should do. This way, you just pass one command-line argument, path to the config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, as far as go is concerned. Command line args are parsed into a [`[]string`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/os/proc.go#L15), so at this level it's just a matter of how much memory is available. But, the comments below are correct. Your system will have its own lower limits that you'll hit first.
2. Same as above.
3. If you find yourself passing *tons* for args for every run:

   - if they don't change much, do they make sense as sane defaults for your flags?
   - if they don't make sense as defaults, consider moving to reading them from a config file. CSV, YAML, whatever.

Without knowing more, I'd recommend a the config file. They make it easy to track different configs/runs, easier to edit than a long list of cmd line args, and you can always write it so that args on the cmd line overwrite values in the config.

Check out [awesome-go](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go) for libraries that already do this, specifically under the [command-line](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#command-line) and [configuration](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#configuration) sections.

Comment: 1 & 2 aren't necessarily true - they're platform and shell dependent. The rest is spot-on though.

Comment: There always has to be a limit to the size of the arguments. ARG_MAX defines it on POSIX systems, mine happens to be `262144` right now.

Comment: Yes, thank you Adrian and JimB. I've added your clarifications to my answer.

Comment: Thank you all! Config files are not an option as the passed in params are dynamic but seems like even the default values would accommodate my needs here. https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/ for future reference